# Flutter Desktop C++ embed

Tags: flutter, ffi

I wanted to know if Flutter supports C/C++ embed via ffi for Desktop applications? I know you can do it for iOS and Android.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop

https://medium.com/flutter-community/integrating-c-library-in-a-flutter-app-using-dart-ffi-38a15e16bc14

Answer (score 0):

According to the api, ffi is compatible with desktop applications for MacOS and Linux [dart:ffi](https://pub.dev/packages/ffi)